# Laravel8 : Passport API after Authenticated

Tags: laravel-8, laravel-passport

I make a login URL for authentication and then if user is logged in will show the token and so on.

Then if i'm fire a API for login again it's redirect to home page as i set on the `authenticated` function but it's a main web page return on postman.

Question is how can i show the custom json return with current token. if user already login in middleware API

Answer (score 0):

ok my bad. it's need to remove middleware for guest in login api so it's no redirect to home page.

```
/**
 * Controller constructor.
 */
public function __construct(
    UserService $userService
) {
    $this->middleware('guest'); // <- remove this line
    $this->userService = $userService;
    $this->response = [
        'error' => false,
        'code' => null,
        'message' => __('message.ajax.success'),
        'data' => (Object)[]
    ];
}
```